# Static text font parameters change

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm creating dialog form for MFC class by editing .rc file with form designer. I have Dialog form and label on it.

[image]

Can't find how to change label's font.

In proprties window I see:

[image]

But there is no font properties. Where they are?

Comment: you need to write code for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to write code for that.
For Example

```
CFont font;
font.CreateFont(
      12,                        // nHeight
      0,                         // nWidth
      0,                         // nEscapement
      0,                         // nOrientation
      FW_NORMAL,                 // nWeight
      FALSE,                     // bItalic
      FALSE,                     // bUnderline
      0,                         // cStrikeOut
      ANSI_CHARSET,              // nCharSet
      OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
      CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
      DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // nQuality
      DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
      _T("Arial"));                 // lpszFacename

 GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC1)->SetFont(&font);
```

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stebcezc.aspx)

[Example](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?386475-How-to-set-font-in-static-text-dialog-box-VC)

Comment: OMG, why in such archaic way? Maybe it is feature, but I can't find reason

Comment: Why in such archaic way? Given that MFC was first released in 1992, I think it seems alright. :)

Comment: how can you change the font size using this? I tried changing the height but nothing happens

Comment: @Dorokun192 could you please show your code, how you are using the code, check ID you are passing in the in GetDlgIem() function.

Comment: @Dorokun192, you should declare "CFont font;" as a member data, not a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

It takes the font of the dialog by default.

If you change the font of the dialog (by changing the properties of the dialog) everything will appear with the same font.

If you want to change only the font of the label you have to proceed with the arcaic way Himanshu told you.